# Geometry terminology: concrete vs. continuous polygons?

Tags: terminology, polygons, geometry

I am trying to find the proper terminologies for 2 kinds of shapes:

- The first type of shape I'm calling "*concrete polygons*". They have a finite number of straight sides (connecting at vertices) and do not have any round/squiggly sides.
- The second type of shape I'm calling "*continous polygons*". They have 1+ curved, rounded or "squiggly" sides, which technically, each consist of infinite sides (since they're "continuous").

Examples:

- Rectangle = concrete
- Circle = continuous
- Line = concrete
- Bezier curve = continuous

**What are the 2 proper geometric terminologies for these 2 kinds of shapes?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the common term is *curvilinear polygon*.

In this context, an ordinary polygon could be called a *linear polygon* or a *straight polygon*.

Comment: Thanks @lhf (+1) - but I guess my question wasn't clear. I'm looking for **two** names here: one name for the first type, and one name for the second. Ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @TicketMonster, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @lhf (+1 again) - can you comment on the difference between your suggested "curvilinear" polygon and studiosus' "*toplogical polygon*"? Thanks again!

Comment: @TicketMonster, I think *curvilinear* sort of implies some degree of smoothness on each part whereas *topological* suggests to me merely continuous with all the pathological possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

You can call your 'continuous polygons' *topological polygons*.

Edit: As for your 'concrete polygons', I would call them simply 'polygons'.

Comment: Thanks @studiosus (+1) - please see my comment underneath lhf's answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: Thanks @studiosus - can you comment on the difference between your suggested "topological" polygon and lhf's "*curvilinear polygon*"? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that these things are all "curves". Some are closed (like rectangles and circles), and some are not.

The property that interests you, I think, is "smoothness". More precisely, you are interested in the presence or absence of "corners" where the (unit) tangent vector is discontinuous. So, circles and lines and Bezier curves are "smooth" (they lack corners), whereas rectangles and polylines are not "smooth".

Answer (score 1):

I would call your "continuous polygons" $1$-dimensional manifolds.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold